# Binomial coefficients modulo a prime $p>5$

Tags: prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

Can we prove that for every prime $p > 5$ the equality
$\binom {2p}{p} \equiv 2\mod p^3$ holds.

Answer (score 4):

By Wolstenholme's theorem, $${2p-1\choose p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p^3}.$$ ${2p-1\choose p-1}=\frac{(2p-1)!}{p!(p-1)!}=\frac{(2p-1)!2p}{p!(p-1)!2p}=\frac{(2p)!}{2p!p!}=\frac{1}{2}{2p\choose p}\equiv1\pmod{p^3}$, so ${2p\choose p}\equiv2\pmod{p^3}.$

Answer (score 2):

$\binom {2\cdot 7}{7} = 2 $ (mod $7^3$)

Answer (score 2):

Did you check it for even one prime $p > 5$? It is already wrong for $p = 7$...

What we can prove, however, is
$${2p \choose p} \equiv 2 \mod{p^3}.$$
You can find more about it on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem).